# Permutations acting on coordinates of codewords

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, permutations, coding-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a binary code of length $n$.  The automorphism group of $\mathcal{C}$ is defined to be the set of permutations in $S_n$ that take $\mathcal{C}$ to itself.  The text by MacWilliams and Sloane (p. 229-230) elaborates further that if $c = (c_1,\ldots,c_n) \in \mathcal{C}$ and $\pi \in S_n$, then we can define $c\pi := (c_{\pi(1)}, \ldots, c_{\pi(n)})$.   As an example, they say if $\pi = (123), \rho=(14)$, then $(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4) \pi = (c_2,c_3,c_1,c_4)$, and $(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4) \pi \rho = (c_2,c_3,c_4,c_1)$. This latter equation is not clear to me.  For if we define $d = c \pi$, we get that $(c \pi) \rho = d \rho = d (14) = (d_4, d_2, d_3, d_1) = (c_4, c_3, c_1, c_2)$, which is not equal to their result. The action of $(1,4)$ is supposed to be to interchange the first and last components of a 4-tuple. And so the effect of $(123)$ followed by $(14)$ is not the same as the effect of $(123)(14)=(1234)$. Am I correct?

Perhaps we need to define the action of $S_n$ on $\{0,1\}^n$ by $c \pi = (c_{\pi^{-1}(1)}, \ldots, c_{\pi^{-1}(n)})$ to get an action, so that $(c \pi) \rho = c (\pi \rho)$?

Comment: You are right about there being an error, but I think you also made a mistake in the calculation of the product of permutations.

Comment: They do mention that "the product $\pi \rho$ means first apply $\pi$, then $\rho$.  So $(123)(14)$ does equal $(1234)$, which is what I wrote above.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Is the error that their definition doesn't give an action (and so we need to use the other definition which has inverses)?

Comment: Ok. If they define the product of permutations that way, then they won't get a right action this way, and it is more complicated. I gotta go proctor an exam now. More later...

Comment: I verified that if we use inverses in the definition, we do get an action. But I don't know whether we can get an action somehow using their definition.

Answer (score 1):

They are defining an action of $S_n$ **from the right** on the set of binary $n$-tuples. The key condition is that the equality
$$
(c\cdot\alpha)\cdot\beta=c\cdot(\alpha\beta)
$$
should hold for all $c$ and all $\alpha,\beta\in S_n$.

Your mistake is in calculating the product
$$
(123)(14)=(1423)
$$
that still should be read from right to left, **because the group operation is composition of functions and this is how we define composition**. In other words, when you calculate the product $(123)(14)$ of permutations, you first apply $\beta=(14)$ to the numbers $1,2,3,4$ and then apply $\alpha=(123)$. But when you apply these
to binary $n$-tuples (instead of their indices) you must reverse the order.

**But...**

You are correct in that with their definition
$$
(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4)(123)(14)=(c_2,c_3,c_1,c_4)(14)=(c_4,c_3,c_1,c_2).
$$
Do notice that this equals $(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4)(1423)$ as it should.

The alternative definition in your last paragraph would give a **left action** of $S_n$, when the above condition is replaced with

$$
(\alpha\beta)\cdot c=\alpha\cdot(\beta\cdot c).
$$